# Git force re-merge of one branch into another

Tags: git, merge, devops, production

I have ***demo*** branch and **master** branch.

When I'm on ***demo*** branch, and I type

```
git merge master
```

it says:

> Already up-to-date.

But when I perform

```
git diff master demo
```

It displays that 1000's of files are different.

I want to have git re-merge from **master** into ***demo***, while keeping the changes in demo which were there like "demo" title etc.. While properly merging (replacing) libraries that were changed.

Comment: Maybe you need to pull changes from  remote master branch before. Do `git checkout master && git pull` before you do the merge.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is a rebase:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

**Explanation:**

The demo branch is like this:

```
demo = old-master + some_changes
```

Git rebase will replace "old-master" with the newer one, and keep the demo changes.

In the end, you will have:

```
demo = master + some_changes
```

Comment: by rebasing, the `demo` will still be different from `master`

Comment: He doesn't want to have demo = master, `I want to have git re-merge master into demo,` **while keeping the changes in demo**, If he wants to have demo = master, he can do a `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: don't do `git reset --hard origin/master`! All changes made in `demo` will be lost!

Comment: @Aleksandar Pavić, did `git rebase origin/master` give you what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

If your `demo` branch diverged from `master`, all commits in `master` will already exist in `demo` unless another branch got merged into `master` in the interim.

If you want to merge the changes in `demo` into `master`, then checkout `master` and then merge `demo`

```
git merge demo
```

Comment: No I want to merge master into demo

Comment: `"Already up-to-date."` means, there are no changes in `master` to be merged into `demo`

Comment: As @ashmaroli pointed out. There no changed in `master` that you don't already have in `demo`. `git diff master demo` only shows the changed that you have made in `demo` compared to master.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, I need forced overwrite of stuff in demo with stuff from master.

Comment: it's still confusing because, you say you need to preserve changes in `demo` like `demo` titles etc

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did, after struggle, and analyzing stuff like git merge strategies

https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies

is manual merge, as follows:

- I've created new folder,
- checked out master from origin into it
- manually copied files from that new folder with master branch to old folder with demo branch
- performed in demo's branch folder: `git add --all`
- then `git commit -m "merged manually"`
- and finally `git push`